# How can I test pages with web services when only Cassini is available (no IIS allowed)?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I'm developing a web site in a high-security environment.  For example, we use CAC cards to authenticate users over SSL.

The site is a mix of VB.NET and C# on .NET 3.5 with some AJAX.  The AJAX parts are now calling web services for things like Cascading Drop Down Lists.

We've been running VS2008 configured on our local PCs to use IIS instead of the default server (Cassini).  However, some security policies were rolled out to the desktops over the weekend and, suddenly, we're not allowed to run IIS on our PCs anymore.

I already have some of our IT people trying to appeal for waivers for developers.  In the meantime, I need to find a way to keep developing.

If I turn off the SSL requirement to the 'secure' part of the application (locally, my PC only) I can serve up some of the pages (using Cassini) when I hit "F5", but pages with web services just bring up "server application unavailable".

I need to be able to add some more functions into the existing web services, among other things, so the ability to single-step through the code is still a necessity.

I'm sure someone who is limited to using Cassini has found a way to Build/Debug pages in VS2008 when webservices are involved.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  As it turns out, some links had "HTTPS://" hard-coded in them (I inherited these).  Changing the link to "~\folder\page.aspx" allowed Cassini to properly serve things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that using Cassini is the default for VS2k8, even for Web Services. Try starting a new HelloWorld web service project and confirm if you can debug it.

OK So that worked. Then change the debugging options of your real project back to using Cassini rather than IIS. I wouldn't move the project (although backing it up might not be a bad idea) as you might be able to get IIS working again.

EDIT: So your actual problem wasn't to do with web services, just hard-coded URLs. (We have similar problem where much of the site works where ever the root of the website is, but some places, such as "main menu" links, expect the root to be the root of the webserver.)

Comment: Well, the "Hello World" worked.  I'm thinking that if I move from the directory-based project (C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\...) to Visual Studio 2008\Projects\...  I might be able to make this part work.  I'm just worried about the solution files - the references and all that.

Comment: Unbelievable cause of the problem - now solved.  Taking the SSL requirement off of the 'secure' section of the website allowed Cassini to work.  HOWEVER - some links had "Https://" hardcoded in them.  Changing them to "~\folder\something.aspx" seems to have done the trick since IE isn't demanding HTTPS (which Cassini can't do).  Will edit my original to reflect what the problem really was.

Comment: @David et all: glad you got it working. My answer will self immolate in 3.2.1....

Answer (score -1):

You proabbly need to contact your IT department and have them open up something on the network so you can call the services - a port on a firewall, for instance.